# Mock not being Injected

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to inject a mock for a unit test but I keep getting a null point exception.

The class I'm trying to test is below, the null pointer seems to be with the ParameterFacade.

When I run the test it doesn't seem to be injecting the mock as the ParameterFacade is null.

```
@Service
public class PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider extends AbstractProcessProvider<PostUnderwriterTransactionInput> {

    @Autowired
    private ParameterFacade parameterService;

    @Override
    public Page startProcess(PostUnderwriterTransactionInput processInput) {

        final PostUnderwriterTransactionContext context = new PostUnderwriterTransactionContext(processInput.getPolicy(),
                setupStrataContextModel(POST_TRANSACTIONS),
                processInput.getTransactionsTypes(),
                processInput.getParameterSelectionCriteria(),
                parameterService.shouldApplyCommissionFromPolicy());

        context.setPostingFromInput(processInput.getAccount().getBalance(),
                processInput.getAccount().getID(),
                getBranch(),
                processInput.getPolicy(),
                processInput.getProcess(),

                null);

        return new AdhocTransactionPostingPage(new TransactionPostingContextModel(context));
    }

}
```

The test is

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProviderTest extends WicketTestCase {

    @ClassRule
    public static MetadataServiceRule metadataServiceRule = new MetadataServiceRule();

    @Mock
    private ParameterFacade mockParameterService;

    @InjectMocks
    private PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider testSubject;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        tester.putBean(mockConversationScopeManager);
        testSubject = new PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider();
        policy = PolicyTestDataBuilder.aPolicy().build();
        account = createAccount();
        testSubject.setUserInfoProvider(MockUserInfoPartyProvider.getMockUserInfoProvider());
        testSubject.setSystemPartyFacade(MockUserInfoPartyProvider.getMockSystemPartyFacade());
        testSubject.setCodeModelFacade(codeModelFacade);
    }

    @Test
    public void startProcessShouldCreateAdhocTransactionPostingPage() {
        // Given
        when(mockParameterService.shouldApplyCommissionFromPolicy()).thenReturn(true);
        final ParameterSelectionCriteriaModel pscm = new ParameterSelectionCriteriaModel();
        final List<TransactionTypeModel> transactions = createTransactionsTypes();
        final PostUnderwriterTransactionInput input = new PostUnderwriterTransactionInput(policy, account, pscm, transactions);

        // When
        final Page page = testSubject.startProcess(input);

        // Then
        assertThat(page, instanceOf(AdhocTransactionPostingPage.class));
        assertThat("Page Default Model is: ", page.getDefaultModelObject(), instanceOf(PostUnderwriterTransactionContext.class));
        assertPageContextValues(page);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any feedback on the provided answers?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 testSubject = new PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider();
```

is overriding the instance created with

```
@InjectMocks
private PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider testSubject;
```

Remove the manual initialization to let the framework behave as designed.

Otherwise, if you want to be able to manually inject the dependency then consider refactoring the class to follow Explicit Dependency Principle

```
@Service
public class PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider 
    extends AbstractProcessProvider<PostUnderwriterTransactionInput> {

    private final ParameterFacade parameterService;

    @Autowired
    public PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider(ParameterFacade parameterService) {
        this.parameterService = parameterService;
    }

    //...omitted for brevity

}
```

This can allow more flexibility when creating the subject

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProviderTest extends WicketTestCase {

    @ClassRule
    public static MetadataServiceRule metadataServiceRule = new MetadataServiceRule();

    @Mock
    private ParameterFacade mockParameterService;

    private PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider testSubject;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        tester.putBean(mockConversationScopeManager);
        testSubject = new PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider(mockParameterService);

        //...omitted for brevity
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    1. ParameterFacade is a spring container managed bean (as it is annotated with @Service and other spring annotations like @Autowired).
    2. @RunWith is configured to use MockitoJUnitRunner which cannot instantiate spring managed container beans

    Hence, in order to handle bean lifecycle in unit tests you'll need to
    1. Use @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    2. Annotate PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider with @Autowired.
    3. Change @Mock to @MockBean on ParameterFacade (org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at you following code, let's see what each line does -

```
@Mock
private ParameterFacade mockParameterService; //1

@InjectMocks
private PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider testSubject; // 2


@Before
public void setup() {
    testSubject = new PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider(); //3
}
```

Line `1` uses spring framework's `@Mock` annotation. This tells spring to mock an object of type `ParameterFacade`, create a mocked **instance** and hold it in the `mockParameterService` variable

Line `2` uses the `@InjectMocks` annotation, which tell spring to use the mocked object created in this test (which we created in line `1`) and use it as a dependency in the variable `testSubject` when creating it. This will result in `testSubject` containing an **instance** of `PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider` that has a dependency of a mocked type `ParameterFacade` `injected to him`

Line `3` creates a new instance of `PostUnderwriterTransactionProcessProvider`. this is pure java, no spring, no mocks, no dependencies. Simply create a new instance of that type the regular way java would do that. The instance that was created in `2` is replaced by this new plain instance and , in a way any assertion will override a previous value, which leaves the variable `testSubject` holding this object